# 'unable to import 'bs4' pylint' - vs code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn web scraping with Python (Python3), but i seem unable to import any packages, specifically BeautifulSoup, i did try to import openpyxl as well and the same error appeared.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

my console immediately flashes with this error:

```
unable to import 'bs4' pyline(import-error) [1,1]
```

My syntax is correct and i have checked to make sure the packages are installed, i have even reinstalled them and they are definitely there.
I am using Mac, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please share the code you are trying and the full error trace.

Comment: Make sure your python interpreter is the same as which you use to install packages. You can see on bottom left corner which one is being used, then go to console and type `pip --version` and see if its the same one. If not, change it to use the right one.

Comment: Amazing that worked, thank you so much! I was on Python 3.9.2. I changed it to Python 3.9.0 and it now works. How do i get it to work on 3.9.2?

Answer (score 0):

If your Python program still runs fine but Pylint throws an `import-error`, then it's likely that Pylint was installed in a different Python binaries than the ones used to run your program.

By default, the Python interpreter in VSCode is set to the first one it finds in the system path, so it's very likely to be `usr/bin/python3` or `usr/local/bin/python3`.

You probably set a different Python binary, e.g. `.pyenv/versions/...` to run your program. That also means that BeautifulSoup is probably installed to this binary.

Pylint has no information of BeautifulSoup that was installed in another location, so it throws an error.

To solve, in VSCode, open Command Palette and select your Python interpreter to the one used to run your program. Then install Pylint for the new interpreter.